# Laravel query with temporary table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

How to convert this query to laravel db query.

```
    SELECT * FROM {
      Select * from organizers
      Order by organizers.rank
} Group by t.department
```

This is simplified version of query. In real the inner query has more where clause and built using laravel db query.

Edit: I am aware of raw query. But that's not what I am looking for. Inner query is complex and has lots of conditional where clause. I would like to retain the db query object I used there.

Comment: Maybe a look at this could help: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: I think people downvoted your question before your edit, before you mentioned that you are aware of raw query (which you really can easily find using a search engine). Maybe also because the title does not really match your needs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have 2 different query builders and merge their binding like below :

```
$innerQuery = DB::table('organizers')->orderBy('organizers.rank');

$mainQuery = DB::table(DB::raw('(' . $innerQuery->toSql() . ') as t'))
    ->mergeBindings($innerQuery->getQuery())
    ->groupBy('t.department')
    ->get();
```

This will also help you retail the `$innerQuery` builder instance for your later use as you have mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to execute a raw query.

```
$result = DB::select("SELECT * FROM (
      Select * from organizers
      Order by organizers.rank
) Group by t.department");
```

reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#raw-expressions

Comment: I know I can use raw query. But as I said the inner query is much complex and has lots of conditional filtering. I would like to retain the db query object of possible.